# como hago para hacer que en "vb YesNo" se me anule un registro cuando le doy a "No" o algo parecido

Tags: vb.net

```
  If MsgBox("¿seguro que desea votar por este partido?", vbYesNo, "Información") = vbYes Then
        MsgBox("Su voto se ah realizado", vbOKOnly, "Información")
    Else
        MsgBox("Su voto se ah cancelado", vbOKOnly, "Información")
    End If
```

tengo esta linea pero cuando quiero "cancelar mi registro" y le doy a "no" aun así se almacena en la base, como hago para solucionarlo?

Comment: hola. que quiere decir que se registra? ahi solo muestras un msgbox...

Comment: No creo que esto esté relacionado con SQL

Comment: talvez no me espicfique bien

Comment: lo que quiero es que cuando me sale el "vbyesno" se anule lo que halla en el cuadro de registro cuando le doy a "no"

Comment: pero falta todo el resto del codigo para eso?? ahi estas solo mostrando un msgbox cuando se presiona no.. por lo cual, no se como queres seguir... cual es el problema? se claro, mira [ask] y usa el boton [edit] para agregar toda la información a la pregunta. Nosotros no estamos en tu cabeza ni vemos tu pc como para saber que necesitas.

Comment: Intenta lo siguiente: `MsgBox("¿seguro que desea votar por este partido?", vbYesNo, "Información") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este método:

Supongamos que el registro se envía a un Label (No especificaste a donde se regsitraba)

```
Dim Texto, Texto2, Título As String 'Texto2 es lo del segundo MsgBox.
Dim Estilo, Estilo2 As MsgBoxStyle
Dim Respuesta As MsgBoxResult


Texto = "¿seguro que desea votar por este partido?"
Estilo = MsgBoxStyle.Question Or MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2 Or 
MsgBoxStyle.YesNo
Título = "Información"

Respuesta = MsgBox(Texto, Estilo, Título)
If Respuesta = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
  Texto2 = "Su voto se ha realizado"
  Estilo2 = MsgBoxStyle.Information Or MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton1 Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly
  ResultadoLabel.Text = "Voto Confirmado"
  MsgBox(Texto2, Estilo2, Título)
ElseIf Respuesta = MsgBoxResult.No Then
  Texto2 = "Su voto se ha cancelado"
  Estilo2 = MsgBoxStyle.Information Or MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton1 Or 
 MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly
 MsgBox(Texto2, Estilo2, Título)
 End If
```

Con esto, si la respuesta es No, no confirmará nada; Pero si la respuesta es "Sí" se registrará en el Label.